# How to move an item from a list box using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a web page contains `2 list boxes` left & Right with transfer arrows.
*I need to `select an item from left` and click on arrow so that it will move to `rigtside list box`*.

I did my code like below, but it is not working.

```
List<WebElement> li = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='availableClients']/div/ul"));
  for (WebElement lit : li) 
  {
      System.out.println(lit.getText());
      if (lit.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("CHKD")) 
      {
        lit.click();
        break;
      }
  }
```

**HTML SOURCE**

```
<div id="availableClients" class="left"> <label for="Available_Clients">Available Clients</label> <div class="list-swap-left"> <span style="width:0"/> <ul class="list-swap-list ui-sortable" title="Select the client to have access to this help link"> <li id="1" class="">abc</li> <li id="22" class="">CHKD</li> <li id="83" class="">Peg</li> <li id="95" class="">Sale</li>
```

Comment: The HTML Source is like below.

<div id="availableClients" class="left">
<label for="Available_Clients">Available Clients</label>
<div class="list-swap-left">
<span style="width:0"/>
<ul class="list-swap-list ui-sortable" title="Select the client to have access to this help link">
<li id="1" class="">abc</li>
<li id="22" class="">CHKD</li>
<li id="83" class="">Peg</li>
<li id="95" class="">Sale</li>

Comment: Can you see "CHKD" printing in console?

Comment: In the Console all items are getting printed

Comment: Ok, so you are gettings the items. But you are clicking on the item itself. Can you post the code you are using to move the item on the other list? Does it works if you do it manually? Also, you have to click on the arrow or on the text to move it to the other column? If you have to click on the arrow like you said, you are clicking on the text and that's why it's not working.

Comment: I have 2 List Boxes one is left & another is on Right. In middle i have arrows.
First I need to select an item in the LHS list box and click on Arrow so that it should move to right.
If i did it manually it is working, but the code is not selecting the item.
after the for loop i have  single line code to click on the arrow.
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("i.icn.cir-fwd")).click();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i myself got the solution:

```
// To Select the Item from List Box
WebElement xps = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
List<WebElement> sli = xps.findElements(By.tagName("li"));  
for (int i = 0; i < sli.size(); i++) 
{
    if (sli.get(i).getText().equalsIgnoreCase(Itemtext)) 
    {
        sli.get(i).click();
        break;
    }
    else{System.out.println("Item not fount in the list");}
}
//Click on Arrow Icon outside the List box to move the Item
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("i.icn.cir-fwd")).click();
```